# WP-Statistics Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given

Tags: php, wordpress, php-8

After updating my PHP from `7` to `8.0.1` I faced this error on `Wordpress 5.3.6`

> The Site Is Experiencing Technical Difficulties.

After checking my email inbox I got this error:

> E_ERROR at line 254 /public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-statistics/includes/vendor/whichbrowser/parser/src/Model/Version.php occured.

and the error message is:

> Error Message: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-statistics/includes/vendor/whichbrowser/parser/src/Model/Version.php:254

It seems the problem is via `WP-Statistics` plugin but there is no update for this plugin.

So please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem in this way. checked `Version.php` file in this path:

```
/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wp-statistics/includes/vendor/whichbrowser/parser/src/Model/Version.php
```

on the live `254` I just replaced:

```
$version .= implode($v, '.');
```

to

```
$version .= implode('.',$v);
```

and the issue is fixed now and my website is running on `PHP 8`